# Scala: passing a contravariant type as an implicit parameter does not choose the nearest supertype?

Tags: scala, implicit, contravariance

Why does the following code does not pick up the implicit val with the nearest supertype?

```
class A
class B extends A

trait TC[-T] { def show(t: T): String }

implicit val showA = new TC[A] { def show(a: A): String = "it's A" }
implicit val showB = new TC[B] { def show(b: B): String = "it's B" }

def doit[X](x: X)(implicit tc: TC[X]): Unit = println(tc.show(x))

doit(new A) // "it's A" as expected
doit(new B) // "it's A" ... why does this not give "it's B" ???
```

If you make `TC` invariant (i.e., `trait TC[T] (...)`), then it works fine and `doit(new B)` returns "it's B" as expected.

By adding another implicit for type `Any`, this issue is even extremer:

```
class A
class B extends A

trait TC[-T] { def show(t: T): String }

implicit val showA = new TC[A] { def show(a: A): String = "it's A" }
implicit val showB = new TC[B] { def show(b: B): String = "it's B" }
implicit val showAny = new TC[Any] { def show(x: Any): String = "it's Any" }

def doit[X](x: X)(implicit tc: TC[X]): Unit = println(tc.show(x))

doit(new A) // "it's Any" ... why does this not give "it's A" ???
doit(new B) // "it's Any" ... why does this not give "it's B" ???
```

And again it work's fine if `TC` is invariant.

What's going on here, and how to solve it?
My goal is to have a contravariant `TC` that implicitly chooses the nearest suitable supertype.

Comment: Related, but somehow not-quite-duplicate: [Implicit Resolution with Contravariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917837/implicit-resolution-with-contravariance)

Comment: Here is also the explanation of the "LowPriorityFoobarImplicits"-trick: [Scala - Co/Contra-Variance as applied to implicit parameter selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195574/scala-co-contra-variance-as-applied-to-implicit-parameter-selection).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `TC[-T]` is contravariant in its type argument, `TC[A]` is a subtype of `TC[B]`, and is therefore considered to be more "specific". That's a well known (and somewhat controversial) design decision, which essentially means that implicit resolution with contravariance sometimes behaves quite unexpectedly.

---

**Workaround 1: prioritizing implicits using inheritance**

Here is how you could use the inheritance and the "LowPriority-*-Implicits" pattern:

```
class A
class B extends A
class C extends B
class D extends C

trait TC[-T] { def show(t: T): String }

trait LowPriorityFallbackImplicits {
  implicit def showA[X <: A]: TC[X] = 
    new TC[A] { def show(a: A): String = "it's A" }
}
object TcImplicits extends LowPriorityFallbackImplicits {
  implicit def showC[X <: C]: TC[X] = 
    new TC[C] { def show(c: C): String = "it's C" }
}

def doit[X](x: X)(implicit tc: TC[X]): Unit = println(tc.show(x))

import TcImplicits._

doit(new A)
doit(new B)
doit(new C)
doit(new D)
```

Now it picks the most specific one in all cases:

```
it's A
it's A
it's C
it's C
```

---

**Workaround 2: invariant helper trait**

Here is how you can forcibly swap the implicits in your particular example by introducing a helper trait that is invariant in the type argument:

```
class A
class B extends A

trait TC[-T] { def show(t: T): String }

val showA = new TC[A] { def show(a: A): String = "it's A" }
val showB = new TC[B] { def show(b: B): String = "it's B" }

trait TcImplicit[X] { def get: TC[X] }
implicit val showAImplicit = new TcImplicit[A] { def get = showA }
implicit val showBImplicit = new TcImplicit[B] { def get = showB }

def doit[X](x: X)(implicit tc: TcImplicit[X]): Unit = println(tc.get.show(x))

doit(new A)
doit(new B)
```

prints

```
it's A
it's B
```

Answer (score 3):

> If there are several eligible arguments which match the implicit parameter's type, a **most specific** one will be chosen using the rules of static overloading resolution. If the parameter has a default argument and no implicit argument can be found the default argument is used.

-[Scala Language Specification - version 2.12](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/07-implicits.html)

Basically, because you make your TypeClass contravariant, it means that `TC[Any] <:< TC[A] <:< TC[B]` *(Where <:< means subtype)*.
And for that `TC[Any]` is considered to be the most specific one.